# Multi Currency Oku Yen?

Tags: multi-currency

Has anyone worked with Oku Yen? We enabled multi currency feature (in the sandbox) and set up Yen to be the corporate currency. But the client wants Oku Yen to be the default currency, where 1 Oku Yen=100 million yen. I can play around with exchange rates to spoof that, but it is not a supported currency and the labels are showing Yen.

Is it possible? Has anyone had similar requirement before? Any workarounds?

Comment: A brief search reveals that "oku" is simply a named value (like "thousand" or "million") that represents 100,000,000 (10^8, one hundred million). The currency is still yen, "oku" just helps deal with otherwise absurdly large numbers.

Comment: Just like writing 100k means 100,000.